# Android sqlite select sub query with count

Tags: android, mysql, select, count, subquery

I have this query in sql

```
UPDATE Flavor a 
SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM recipes c 
WHERE c.flv1name = a.name)
```

which returns a count of all entries from table called recipes in a column named flv1name. It then updates a second table called flavors in a column named count with the total number of entries from flv1name like this.

```
Table Flavors
_id         name         count
1           Apple        2
2           Berry        1
3           Cherry       4
```

the question is, how do I write this statement in a database helper in my android application?

Here is what I have so far

```
      public Cursor syncflavorcount() {
          mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
          String buildSQL = "UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " a SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " c WHERE c.flv1name = a.name) ";


    return mDb.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `mDb.update("UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " a SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " c WHERE c.flv1name = a.name)")`

Comment: Thanks, i think the issue is with the nDb.update. It is calling for a different format instead of a compiled statement. Hence the question. How to write this statement in my DBAdapter for Android.

Comment: Ok I ran the code after some changes and it errors out with this.   
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "a": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE flavors a SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recipes c WHERE c.flv1name = a.name))

Answer (score 0):

For this to work in a Android application Data Adapter the alias have to be removed.

From this

```
mDb.update("UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " a SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " c WHERE c.flv1name = a.name)")
```

To This

```
mDb.update("UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " +DATABASE_TABLE2+ ".flv1name = " +DATABASE_TABLE+".name)");
```